# Using Exchange Web Service, How to find unread mail count of multiple Email Id's

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I have around 50 mail boxes or 50 group email id

I want to make a desktop application using C#.

No guarantee Outlook will be installed in that machine, so prefer to get a solution, which is depend on outlook library etc

My requirement is to loop this 50 mail box and find the below information.

1) Count of unread mail in each of these mailboxes
2) Unread mail’s date, subject and size

**Please note, it is not one single email id, it is 50 group email id (eg support@XYZ.com)**

I think it can be achieved using **Exchange Web Service** (Our exchange server is 2007).
So can someone tell me how to pass username, password and other details to enter 50 different group ids and get the unread mail count and details?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Have you tried anyting or you are just expecting us to write it for you?